# ubuntu 16.04 LTS fails with an error " an installation error occured" while pxe booting

Tags: vmware, 16.04

I am attempting to PXE boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on as a vm on VMware ESX 5.1 U3.
The installation via iso works successfully however PXE install fails at a point post partitioning saying:

```
an installation error occurred.
```

Upon pressing <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> it shows this error:

```
base-installer: could not find any live images
```

I am unsure whether this is a bug with 16.04 as the same preseed file worked wonderfully well with Ubuntu 14.04. I also followed the following URL to overcome this error faced by many on Ubuntu 14.04 however this did not resolve the issue for 16.04.
URL: http://www.michaelm.info/blog/?p=1378

Could someone please tell me if any new parameter needs to be added as the preseed file somehow doesn't read the `filesystem.squashfs`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug - I reported the same question yesterday shortly after you did, and have continued to research it.  Askubuntu didn't find your question because my search-fu is weak I guess.

You'll notice in the logs that it prepended /cdrom in front of the URL you gave for the live-installer image.  Previous versions didn't do this, and I found a changelog where they claim to have stripped all occurrence of /cdrom prefixes, but it doesn't seem to be happening.  This is why I get frustrated with Ubuntu LTS releases - I thought they were supposed to be corporate oriented, but they seem to fail to test corporate type things.

I've filed a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/live-installer/+bug/1575652 - you may want to add your input there.

Comment: Thanks so much Tony. I have posted my comment in addition to yours on the URL given by you and have registered to this site so I can post more bugs as and when I find this. Good to know that this is a bug. I have been breaking my head trying to find a work around to this problem. However I couldn't. Let's see if the developer manages to fix this. This is critical for me as I need to do a POC of this OS and if successful, I may need to mass deploy this via PXE install.